# Cube comparison test from Kit of factor

Tags: pattern

Are this cubes the same or different? 
[image: Manual for Kit of. Factor-Referenced. Cognitive Tests. Ruth B. Ekstrom. John W. French. Harry H. Harman with Diran Dermen. 1976.]

The answer key says they are the same, but to me, they do not look like they are.

Source: Kit of. Factor-Referenced. Cognitive Tests. Ruth B. Ekstrom. John W. French. Harry H. Harman with Diran Dermen. 1976.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Are you asking whether they're merely the same size, or whether they're literally the same cube from two different angles? Just from eyeballing it, they look the same size, but I'm not sure how you'd be expected to prove that they are (or are not) the exact same cube.

Comment: They ask you if the cubes are the same or different from different angles

Comment: You have left out the crucial bits of information that make this solvable: 1) there won't be an identical symbol on any two sides of a cube, and 2) you are supposed to only mark "D" if the cubes are guaranteed to be different, and "S" if they could be the same. These details are made abundantly clear in [the source](https://www.ets.org/Media/Research/pdf/Kit_of_Factor-Referenced_Cognitive_Tests.pdf) and the only confusion arises from omitting them.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure

> The cubes MAY or MAY NOT be the same.

Because

> You can rotate both cubes in a way which hides the 3 faces shown, and show the 3 faces hidden, therefore they can be interchangeable. But you've no guarantees that the hidden part of each one is the same as the visible part of the other.

Answer (score 0):

For me these cubes

> Are not the same

Because

> You have 3 solutions for the final cube.
>  If D and F are top and bottom, letters H and E will be upside-down compared to the letters G and I.
>  If D and I are top and bottom, F and G will be on the side compared to H and E.
>  If D and G are top and bottom, F and I will be on the other side compared to H and E.
>  If you make a cube you will at least try to put most letters in the same way to facilitate reading. With this cube, no matter the side, you can't have 4 letters in the same way.

Comment: How do you put all the letters in the same way on a cube?

Comment: At least 4 of them, you obviously will need at a moment a top and a bottom, but you will try to align them. Edited my answer

Comment: by googling 'dice with letters', I ended up with this picture (https://goo.gl/images/MhGdFd) wich shows dices that do not follow your patern. I still think your answer is the right one since most of the dices i found follow your logic

Comment: You're right, my answer is not valid for these dice. However the other dice from this image suggestions seem to follow the rule but with letters on top on each other instead of side-by-side. Always hard to tell with 3 sides only

Answer (score 0):

> These are not the same, as these are not even cubes.
>
> The only way to see the front side as a square, is an angle where from you can't see any other sides.

Answer (score 0):

By searching a bit I found that

> It is the same cube (the official solution states that they are the same)
>  After reading the explanations on this kind of tests (p. 152 of the [Manual for Kit of Factor](https://www.ets.org/Media/Research/pdf/Manual_for_Kit_of_Factor-Referenced_Cognitive_Tests.pdf) I think that because you have 6 different letters, no letter can overlap and point a difference between the 2 cubes, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

For me these cubes

> Possible to be the same, and possible to be diffrent:

Because (I don't know how to hide images, I made it on word, so continue only if you want to see profound explanation):

> [image: ![]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd2oJ.jpg)
>
> [image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et45b.jpg)